# nvcc error, "no command" verifying installation of CUDA 10 on Debian 9 Stretch

Tags: nvidia

After installing CUDA 10.0 on Debian 9 Stretch, verifying the installation throws this error:

```
$ nvcc -V
$ No command 'nvcc' found
```

Why?

References: [Debian CUDA Installation Guide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218163/how-to-install-cuda-toolkit-7-8-9-on-debian-8-jessie-or-9-stretch/#answer-241127)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Solution: Permanently change **PATH** & **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** by editing the .bashrc file

---

Fix in 3 steps:

1. Create .bashrc file in ~/home directory

`$   cd ~/`

`$   sudo touch .bashrc`

2. Enter the file:

`$   sudo gedit .bashrc`

---

[3. Scroll to the botton and add PATHs to the .bashrc file:](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup)

```
#CUDA Environment Setup
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
```

Save File.

Reboot.

Open new terminal:

```
$   nvcc -V
```

Result:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130
```

[CUDA Toolkit Documentation Here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#environment-setup)