# "Hermetically" override a distribution-installed CUDA with a locally-installed version

Tags: software-installation, cuda

In my Devuan GNU/Linux Beowulf distribution (which is essentially Debian Buster without systemd), CUDA 10.1 is installed. I don't want to uninstall it for various reasons; but - I do want to use a different CUDA version, which I have placed under `/usr/local/cuda-10.2`.

When the existing CUDA version isn't integrated into the distribution - this is pretty easy: Just re-target the `/usr/local/cuda` symlink to point to `/usr/local/cuda-X2.Y2` instead of `/usr/local/cuda-X1.Y1`, and make sure any environment variables mentioning CUDA regard the symlinked path instead of the version-specific path. But what's going to stop applications from using `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so` or `/usr/include/cuda_runtime.h`? That's so tempting! :-(

I would like a checklist, as robust as possible, of changes I need to make - to environment variables, to symlinks, to entries in configuration files - to make sure my local version gets used. Of special interest are packages built with CMake or with (sigh) autotools.

Notes:

- The nVIDIA kernel driver version remains the same (CUDA 10.2 can live with the distribution-provided version, it seems).
- This question is *not* about how to install the local version of CUDA. In a sense, it's *complementary* to questions like [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/218163/34868).

Comment: Please add a tag wiki and excerpt for the new tag that you're mass adding to posts

Comment: @muru: Yes, I was going to, will go do it now...